# HTML5/Javascript : Run video via Proxy

Tags: javascript, html, video, proxy

Is there a way to send **media metadata** from browser to a server via a **Proxy** ?

*Example*

```
<video><source src="http://domain.com/video.mp4"></video>
```

> When client watches this video, the browser send data to the server
>   http://domain.com/ with his IP. I want to pass via a Proxy.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If the video is being hosted on a standard web server I don't see any reason why you would not be able to proxy the connection, in addition the proxy server logs or in the case of direction downloads the web server logs would show the IP address of the downloader. If you are planning on using a video streaming server then many of them support proxying connections. This will really depend on your planned implementation.

Comment: The video is hosting on server A. The website is hosting on server B. But when the user play the video, the metadata are sended as client IP. How can we change the user IP by Proxy ?

Comment: Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/php-proxy/. It is a simple PHP based proxy script. Whatever the language server a supports if you use a basic proxy script on the server to proxy the video data then the server logs on server b will show the server a IP address.